# Rails 5, minitest 5, I can not deactivate "fail-fast"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

In one of my last projects the tests are breaking after the first fail. Investigating a bit I see this is the expected behaviour when you activate `fail fast`:

```
rails test -f
```

But I am running plane:

```
rails test
```

And still the tests are not all executed.

What is making the `fail fast` to be activate in my project by default? How can I prevent this?

I am pasting my Gemfile.lock here: https://pastebin.com/FD8dEnUE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a known bug (https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/730).

A quick and dirty fix is to lock *minitest* version on your `Gemfile`:

```ruby
gem "minitest", "5.10.3"
```

Since rails *5.0.x* is not on maintenance mode anymore (as per https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32547#issuecomment-380930889) you might need to downgrade *minitest* version until you are able to upgrade Rails to >= *5.1x*